# JavaScript - setInterval() gets crazy after opening another tab on the browser

Tags: javascript

I have a simple function that converts seconds into the format HH:MM:SS, I am using setInterval() to run each second. Surprisingly, when executing the page for the first time, the clock seems to be working fine. However, when leaving it for a while and opening another window/tab in the browser and going back to it, the clock gets crazy and the setInterval seems to be executing 3 or 4 times each second.

```
formatTimeToHours(seconds){
return new Date(seconds * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
}

 clock(){
 let number = 0;
setInterval(()=>{
     number += 1;
     this.timer = this.formatTimeToHours(number)
}, 1000)
}
```

Comment: Not an expert, but maybe you left the tab and all those setInterval loops were queued, then when you came back they had to catch up?

Comment: @AndrewLi that's a possibility

Comment: @AndrewLi no concrete solution was given on the supplied link

Comment: @Folky.H, if you don't like the answers the appropriate solution is to set a bounty on the question rather than asking a new one.